# How did Antiquity deal with the disappearance of the Transcendent?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, plato, nietzsche, continental-philosophy, existentialism

In Western Philosophy, Existentialism heeding Nietzches call was the first philosophy that dealt with the loss of the transcendent in a formal way.

Whereas prior to him, it anchored, or rather was the *telos* of Hegels thought, and Kant placed it beyond the possibility of any critical inquiry.

Reading back into history, and taking Plato as beginning philosophy, that is primarily *logos* rather than *mythos*, can we take Platos Forms as a return to the transcendent in the mode of *logos*, that which led to the dispersal of the Homerian gods?

(One notes that Plato is after the Milesian materialists).

Comment: Too complicated! summarize it in one word (c) Bender.

Comment: Have you seen SEP's [Plato's Myths](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plato-myths/)?

Comment: @labreur: no - thanks for pointing it out; I've been looking for something like that - do you know of something similar for Aristotle?